# How do I get token from Paypal with PAW?

Tags: paw-app

In the example of paypal:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "Client ID: Secret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

But I don't know how to setting with the -u "Client ID: Secret", in PAW everything about the auth is setting with the header

Answer (score 0):

To get your access token from PayPal you should authenticate using HTTP Basic Auth, set Authorization header to the Basic Auth dynamic value and set your client id and secret as input for the dynamic value.
[image: basic-auth-dynamic-value]

Make sure that your request body is Form URL-Encoded :

[image: request-body]

You can also import your cURL into Paw by going to File>Import>Text and pasting cURL there (you can install cURL importer from https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/cURLImporter) It will automatically create a request in Paw.

Comment: But Paypal return with an error: 415 Unsupported Media Type :(

Comment: have you also set the ``grant_type`` to ``client_credentials`` in the Form URL-Encoded request body?

Comment: yes, I just import the cURL code like you said, but paw turn the -u param into the -H

the code below the dialog:

`curl -X "POST" "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
 -H "Authorization: Basic Q2xpZW50IElEOioqKioqIEhpZGRlbiBjcmVkZW50aWFscyAqKioqKg==" \
 -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -d $'"grant_type=client_credentials"`

Comment: looks like Paw is not setting the Content-type header correctly for you, I suggest you set it to ``application/x-www-form-urlencoded`` manually